# How do you word wrap in Firefox and IE 10 while using display: -moz-box and -ms-flexbox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, internet-explorer-10

When you use `word-wrap: break-word;` with `display: -moz-box;` and `display: -ms-flexbox` the text doesn't wrap.

When using the Chrome version: `display:-webkit-box;` everything works great.

Here is an example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d6Y4Z/4/)

How do you center vertically and use word-wrap in IE and Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the text in `<p>` tags and then apply the following css:

```
p{
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
}
```

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/d6Y4Z/10/

Answer (score 4):

I had issues using `word-wrap: break-word` in combination with `display: flex;` on a parent div and a child that is set to `flex-grow: 1`. I found the solution in a discussion in [this Firefox bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1136818).

Setting `min-width: 0; word-wrap: break-word;` on the child worked.

The reason for this behavior, taken from that bug report, is:

> That flex item has the (new default) "min-width:auto", and on flex items, that makes them *refuse* to shrink smaller than their min-content size -- the length of the text.
>
> To work around this & allow the flex item to shrink, you need to do two things:
>    (1) Put the raw text inside of an *explicit flex item* (e.g. a ), rather than putting it directly inside of the flex container -- so that you can style it. (You can't style an anonymous flex item.)
>    (2) Style that flex item with "min-width:0".

Comment: Except your issue is unrelated to this 3+ year old post about obsolete and non-standard CSS properties that are unrelated to flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue today, managed to get it working just a few minutes ago:
http://jsfiddle.net/lmartins/3dHDd/

The key for me was to have the label with `display: inline-block`and then flexbox declaration `-ms-flex: 0 1 100%;`, where the last parameter, flex-basis, can be whatever you desire.